# Apache Web Server Problem

Tags: apache-2.2

In my office, I have a newly installed server machine and 15 client machines. In my server machine I installed apache web server which is running without any inturuption. But the client machines did not find my server's apache web server. Here is the details for you:

```
Server Machine IP : 192.168.0.1
Client Machine IP : 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.0.25
```

I use the following from my server to view my apache server: 
    http://localhost/ 
    http://192.168.0.1/ 
    http://127.0.0.1/

I use the following from my client machines to view my apache server: 
    http://192.168.0.1/

BUT from my client machines I can not find my apache server of my server machine.

Anybody can answer me, what is my fault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say if you're running on Linux or Windows, which would be helful.

This type of problem sounds like there's a firewall on the server that is blocking incoming traffic on port 80 (HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a lot of information.  For one, what does 'can not find' mean?  Do you get nothing?  Do you get an error page?  Do you get content but not what you expected?  What do your error and access logs say?  Do they have any connections from clients?  If they do, do they show errors?

In cases like these you need to break down the possible issues and have a check that isolates the individual problem.

From the server machine: Check the error logs first.  Do they indicate any connections?  If not, maybe network error.  If they do show connections, what does it say about them?

Check the config file httpd.conf.  Do you have any Limit sections?

From the server, can you ping the client machine?  Can the client machine ping the server machine?  Check for general networking issues first.  You don't mention what OS the server machine is running, are there other services (like file sharing) on the server machine that is available to the client machine?

On the server machine (again, you didn't mention OS) you should do a netstat and see what sockets are LISTENing.  Is port 80 in LISTEN state?  Is it LISTENing to all interfaces (*) or just 127.0.0.1?  If it's just on 127.0.0.1 then you can never have a client see it, and you'll need to change your config.

If it's up and see it LISTENing for all interfaces, go to a client machine, use raw HTTP to verify connection.

```
telnet 192.168.0.1 80
```

do you get any indication that it connects?  Or just waiting, then times out.  If it times out, maybe you have firewall issues, and have to configure your server OS.
if it connects, do a simple HTTP request for the home page,

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
[return]
[return]
```

Do you get anything?  what response code (do a search on HTTP RESPONSE CODE to see them all).  Is a permissions issue?  Authorizations?

Go back to the server.  Check the log on the server, notice anything new?

This should be enough to isolate your issue.  You really need to gather more information for your questions.